# Is the graph complete?Answer not matching

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, ring-theory

Consider the ring $\mathbb Z_{12}$. Consider  a graph such that the vertices of the graph are the non-zero and non-trivial ideals of $\mathbb Z_{12}$, and any two vertices $I,J$ are adjacent if and only if $I+J$ has non-zero intersection with every other ideal. Draw the graph.

**My try**:
The non-zero and  non-trivial ideals of  $\mathbb Z_{12}$ are $(2),(3),(4),(6)$. Now $(2),(3)$ are adjacenct since $(2)+(3)=\mathbb Z_{12}$ and that has non-zero intersection with every other ideal. Similarly, $(3),(4)$ are adjacenct since $(4)+(3)=\mathbb Z_{12}$ and that has non-zero intersection with every other ideal.

Moreover,  $(2),(6)$ are adjacenct since $(2)+(6)=(2)$ and that has non-zero intersection with every other ideal. Similarly, $(3),(6)$ are adjacenct since $(6)+(3)=(3)$ and that has non-zero intersection with every other ideal.

Proceeding like this, I found that the graph is a complete graph.

But the answer my professor gave shows that it is not complete. Can someone pleaese help me out?

**If someone can point out where I am wrong, I will be grateful.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Similarly, $(3),(6)$ are adjacenct since $(6)+(3)=(3)$ and that has non-zero intersection with every other ideal.

Is this the case?

$(3) = \{0,3,6,9\}$ does not intersect $(4) = \{0,4,8\}$ nontrivially.

Comment: Ah, I got that. Can I ask one more question please? Will the graph be connected?

Comment: If you can go from any vertex of the graph, to any other vertex using only the edges, it will be connected. Draw a picture of the finished graph, and see if you can travel between each pair of nodes, and the answer will be immediate.